# OpenCV kmeans with CV_64F1

Tags: c++, opencv

According to the docs and the error that I get:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (data.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0)
```

OpenCV's kmeans clustering doesn't support CV_64F1 typed Arrays. Is there something I'm overlooking or would I have to implement kmeans by hand?

(I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0  C++ Intefaces with gcc 5.3.1 on Linux;
and yes, I need the 64 Bit precision, I'm doing some machine learning data analysis.)

Edit: On second thought, it would be worth a try to "down cast" the Matrix to 32F, since I only need the k-means clustering to initialize my factors for the NMF. Maybe the result will be still better than random initialization. Is there a way to convert an OpenCV Matrix?

Comment: Many opencv algorithms are optimized for certain cases and may not exist for other types of data. So yes, you'd have to do it yourself

Comment: Is your edit asking if there's a way to convert a CV_64F to a CV_32F? Of course!

Comment: Yes, I fired to quickly on that one. I edited just after the post, because it came to me, that converting to lower precision might still work. Only then did I look into the docs. Testing it right now. Probably should close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to conclude this question:

I simply converted the Matrix from 64F to 32F:

```
cv::Mat a32f;
a.convertTo(a32f, CV_32FC1);

kmeans(a32f,k, labels,
    cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::COUNT , 10, .0001),
    5, cv::KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS);
```

with `a` being a parameter of type cv::Mat CV_64FC1